# What do you call the small wooden plates that people write wishes in and hang on some stand in a shrine?

Tags: words, culture, religion

What do you call the small pieces of wood(?) where people write wishes on and hang them on some stand close to where you tie folded o-mikuji (おみくじ)? Or are they also called おみくじ?

Related question:
Also, in some temples, there's also this little cabinet where you can put a lighted candle (I remember seeing one in a temple near Ueno Park). What do you call that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1  I think it's [[絵馬]{えま}](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ema_(Shinto)).

[image: 絵馬]

2  Maybe [献灯台]{けんとうだい}?

[image: 献灯台]